# Cookie security php

Tags: php, security, cookies

I'm using a basic cookie system for the "remember me" part of a log in form. Here is the code:

```
    if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
$username = $_POST['username'];
$password = $_POST['password'];

    if($username&&$password)
    {
        $connect = mysql_connect('localhost','root','');
        mysql_select_db('phplogin');
        $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM utilisateurs WHERE NomUtilisateur='$username' AND MotDePasse='$password'");

        $rows = mysql_num_rows($query);
        if($rows==1)
        {
            if($_POST['checkbox'])
            {
                setcookie('username',$username,time()+3600);
                header('Location: membre.php');     

            }else{$_SESSION['username']=$username;header('Location:membre.php');}
        }else echo "Something something error";
    }else echo "Something something darkside";
}
```

I'm not quit sure if I need to secure the cookie and if yes, how to do it? All I really want to do is not allowing people to log in in another user account with a fake cookie or put sensitive information on the clear in the cookie.

Comment: Right now anyone can create a cookie to log himself in as any user as long as he knows his username. Besides that, storing a plaintext password in your database is a **huge no-go**!

Comment: Well, that isn't good at all =/

Comment: I still didn't add all the crypt part on my code. Everything is still in a localserver, so no problem.

Comment: Well, if you don't add it now chances are good that you'll forget or be too lazy to add it later

Comment: Your code is also vulnerable to [SQL injections](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/SQL_Injection).

Comment: You should use session_start() instead of rolling your own,  very insecure session.  Also yes,  this is flagrant sql injection. outch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently anybody can log himself if he knows the username of a user. Even if a cookie is set you need to have a process to identify users that they are genuine clients..like for ex., when a user logs in you can save a random alphanumeric string saved in the cookies and your DB against that user, and the next time you cross check the string with the value in your DB  and remember to change the alphanumeric string after every X days, this prevents attackers from copying someone’s cookies and using them to login. Something like this do

```
$uniquekey     = 'A234W';
$randomstring  = sha1(strval(rand(0,microtime(true))+ $uniquekey + strval(microtime(true))));
setcookie( 'loginID', $randomstring, time()+60*60*24*7,'/', 'www.yoursite.com', false, true);
```

and when reading from cookie use `mysql_real_escape_string` to filter any malicious code

Comment: With this code only the `microtime(true)` part is actually the hash input since you’re using arithmetic addition.

Comment: That doesn’t matter. With arithmetic addition, `'A234W'` results in `0`.

Comment: i just gave an example..he can use any random string generators..:)

Comment: -1,  you should use session start instead of rolling your own.

Comment: @Rook i guess cookie can be useful,provided you use it securely

Comment: @Sibu and you are not,  you are reinventing the wheel and its awful.